# Display value of attribute of type SDO_GEOMETRY

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use JDBC to display rows in a table created in an Oracle 11g Database, the problem is I don't manage to get the value of the attribute "SHAPE" of type "SDO_GEOMETRY" using the following code, which by the way works fine when it comes to the other attributes of the table :

```
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver O.K.");

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            String user = "system";
            String passwd = "isima";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            System.out.println("Connexion effective");

            Statement myStmt = null;
            ResultSet myRs = null;          

            myStmt = conn.createStatement();

            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testGeo");

            while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("shape"));

            } 

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here are the DDL statements used to create the testGeo table and some test data.

```
CREATE TABLE testGeo (
  GeoID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(32),
  shape SDO_GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO testGeo VALUES(
  1,
  'cola_a',
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7)
  )
);

INSERT INTO testGeo VALUES(
  2,
  'cola_b',
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2,1, 6,7)
  )
);

INSERT INTO testGeo VALUES(
  3,
  'cola_c',
  SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 9,9)
  )
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the DDL statements used to create the `testGeo` table and some test data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204200/how-to-retrieve-sdo-geometry-from-database-using-jdbc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The problem itself is caused by the fact that you are trying to retrieve a complex object that is a custom Oracle object which should be handled with its own mapping library.** The `SDO_GEOMETRY` type as used here in you example statement:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(
   2003,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),
   SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7)
)
```

is part of the Oracle Spatial package and relies on custom objects. These cannot be read as easily as basic SQL columns like `VARCHAR` or `NUMBER`, that is why your `getString("shape")` call yields no results.

The solution is to use the [JGeometry package](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14373_02/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html) provided by Oracle that is designed exactly for this purpose:

> A Java class that maps Oracle Spatial's SQL type MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY.
>   Supports only Oracle JDBC Driver version 8.1.7 or higher. Provides
>   basic access functions to the geomeries stroed in Oracle Spatial
>   database.

With this library on classpath you would be able to use the custom Java mappings to manipulate your shape object:

```
/// reading a geometry from database
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT shape FROM testGeo");
STRUCT st = (oracle.sql.STRUCT) rs.getObject(1);
//convert STRUCT into geometry
JGeometry j_geom = JGeometry.load(st);
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can do the same using Hibernate ?

Comment: Hibernate 5 is not supported (yet, I guess), but otherwise there is official support for Spatial from the Hibernate team: http://www.hibernatespatial.org/.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [JGeometry](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14373/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html) class in the Oracle Spatial Java package for this. You can call the spatial type, like:

```
// Read a geometry from the DB.
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT shape FROM testGeo where name='cola_a'");
STRUCT stGeo = (oracle.sql.STRUCT) rs.getObject(1);
JGeometry jGeo = JGeometry.load(stGeo);
// Use jGeo to fetch the required data.
```

If you need to write the Geometry back to Database, you can try this:

```
 // Write a geometry back to the DB.
 PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE testGeo set shape=? where name='cola_a'");
 STRUCT stGeo = JGeometry.store(jGeom, connection);
 ps.setObject(1, stGeo);
 ps.execute();
```

*Note: Refer the JGeometry documentation for the usage of the class APIs.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like

```
select g.geoid, g.name, go.column_value
from testgeo g, table(g.shape.SDO_ORDINATES) go;
```

but you will get one row for each number in the shape.

Comment: The problem is actually that I get "null" as value of the attribute SHAPE of each row of my table, when I try to access my database using JDBC as showed above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error is with `getString()` because SDO_GEOMETRY can not be transformed to a string. I have no knowledge of oracleDB to be honest, so it is just a guess.

Have you tried `getInt()` or `getByteArray()` or similar options?

There are a whole lot of possibilitys when getting data from the database.