# How can i pass a Double[] array to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

Bundle object doesn't let me pass a Double[] array because it require a double[] array. i'm not able to cast double[] to Double[] and I don't know what to do.

Help me please.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to help clarify the issue that you are having.

Comment: why you dont do to create a Double[] manually, and copy from double[]

Comment: According to [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double), the only option appears to be looping through and unboxing (or boxing in your case) the array - by a third party library or your own code.

Comment: try to serialize, then add to a getSharedPreferences, and read in the other activity... and unserialize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the Double array and populate the double array by assigning to every value the output of Double.doubleValue(); Once that is done you can put your double[] array in the Bundle

```
Double D[];
double d[];
for(int i=0 ; i<D.length ; ++i) {
    d[i] = D[i];
}
```

Of course I did not initialize the variables but it's merely to give an example

**Update**
For anyone reading this I have also found this similar question that can be useful. It is abount using a 3rd party library to solve this problem and some comments add some nice information abount performance in different scenarions. Check it out: [How do I convert Double[] to double[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double?lq=1)

Comment: There is not need to do this. `Double` is **[autoboxed and unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)**. Though it is an object, it can be used as a value.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli then please explain how one could put a Double[] in a Bundle using Unboxing

Comment: Oh sheesh, I guess I didn't read the question clearly enough. You're right.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli not a problem...but could my code be improved using unboxing instead of Double.doubleValue(); ? Would that work better?

Comment: Oh yeah, you could just say `d[i] = D[i]`.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli good, thank you, I edited my answer with this information

Comment: i get it, but i was looking for a better way. anyway it works, so.. that's ok