# How to box double array to Double array when adding to Map?

Tags: java, hashmap, boxing

I want to fill up a `HashMap<Integer,Double[]>`

```
Map<Integer,Double[]> cached_weights = new HashMap<Integer,Double[]>();
```

with just regular `int` and `double[]`, what's the best way to do that?

I see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double), but it answers the opposite question.

Comment: It's called "boxing".

Comment: If you want to use `int` type as key instead of `Integer` then this is impossible. Also `Double[]` and `double[]` are not covariant, and `double[]` will not be automatically boxed to `Double[]`.

Comment: Also, a `Double[]` is *not* a boxed `double[]` (boxing doesn't apply to arrays), and you can store a `double[]` in a hashmap already anyway.

Comment: An `int` will "auto box" to an `Integer`. That is not the case for a `double[]`, however. You will have to manually change the `double[]` into a `Double[]`.

Comment: yeah that's right about double[] but still, what about int to Integer?

Comment: so int just automatically becomes Integer?

Comment: Auto boxing is syntactic sugar where the compiler automatically calls Integer.valueOf for you.

Comment: "so int just automatically becomes Integer" yes, that is how boxing works. If you have `int` you can store it in `Integer` variable (code handling conversion from primitive `int` to object `Integer` - `Integer.valueOf` - will be added by compiler for you).

Comment: hmm, that's convenient. is it considered bad style?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java for how to convert double[] to Double[]

Comment: Silly question: why not use a `Map<Integer, double[]>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the key (Integer) the compiler will handle this automatically for you and you can pass directly an int value.

For the Boolean array, you could handle this way with Java 8

```
Map<Integer, Double[]> foo = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
double[] bar = new double[10];
//As you can see, 1 is passed directly and will be converted to Integer object.
foo.put(1, Arrays.stream(bar)
            .boxed()
            .toArray(Double[]::new));
```

the `boxed` method of [DoubleStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) returns a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, boxed to Double.

Then you get a Stream on which you can easily call `toArray` to convert to a `Double[]`.