# How to form a java.util.List<java.lang.Double> from double[]

Tags: java

I'm using a function (which I don't own so can't change its return type) that returns a `double[]`

I'm trying to create a `java.util.List<java.lang.Double>` from it.

If *only* the function returned a `Double[]`, then I could use `Arrays.asList(...)` but that doesn't work for `double[]`.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Google Guava has a helper for that - "List<Wrapper> asList(prim... backingArray)  Wraps a primitive array as a List of the corresponding wrapper type. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will unfortunately need to iterate through the entire array and create a new `double[]` array from scratch.

Look up boxing and unboxing to learn more about this phenomenon.

Per answer here: [How do I convert Double[] to double[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use streams to convert the array:

```
double[] d = ...;
List<Double> d2 = DoubleStream.of(d).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```