# How to convert a Double[] to double...?

Tags: java

Given a method definition:

```
public void create(double... values);
```

This method is called like this:

```
List<Double> values = ...;
Double[] doubles = values.toArray(new Double[0]);
create(doubles);  // wont work
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Overload the method (`void create(Double... values)`). `Double[]` and `double[]` cannot be converted into each other.

Comment: You need to manually convert `Arrays.stream(input).mapToDouble(Function.identity()).toArray()`.

Comment: well, the method above is the only means to do it, no other method is available

Comment: Note: `double[]` (array of primitives) is not the same as `Double[]` (array of references) To create a `double[]` from a `Double[]` you have to create a new array and copy all the values out of it. Best to avoid creating arrays of wrappers in the first place.

Comment: @Turing85 but then you're still in the same pickle - you need to convert `Double[]` to `double[]` in the method overload.

Comment: @BoristheSpider true that. But the question is: what does the method do? If it iterates over the varargs and does something with each value, autoboxing will take care of that.

Comment: @Turing85 you're not suggesting simply copying the code from one method to another are you? I mean, if there are two lines in the method then maybe; but what if there are 5 lines? 10? Where do you draw the line...?

Comment: ok. so the problem *is not* `double[] -> double...`, the problem is `Double[] -> double[]`. Check. About the example above: Its a stripped-down version of the actual code i have. the method does not return `void`, but an actual object, but it doesn't matter wrt the question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I say that no further speculation is of use as long as the functionality of the method is unknown

Comment: @Turing85 but what else is there to do on a Tuesday morning? You don't mean _work_ do you. Eugh!

Comment: @helt Don't to `Double[] doubles = values.toArray(new Double[0])`, do `values.stream().map(Double::doubleValue).toArray()` instead. That way you only copy once. Also, never do `.toArray(new Xxxx[0])` as it creates an empty array, then discards it and creates an array of the correct size. You of course know the correct size to begin with so use it.

Comment: wow. so many mistakes in 2 loc :)

Comment: @helt 1) every non-trivial program contains at least one bug. 2)
every non-trivial program can be simplified by at least one line of code.
Therefore: every non trivial program can be simplified to one line of code. With a bug.

Comment: @BoristheSpider at least it isn't monday ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] unboxed = Stream.of(boxed).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30117592/3635454

Comment: Note that this does copy the whole array; which is of course necessary to answer the question as it stands (you have my vote). But it should probably be avoided if possible, as it's really a waste of CPU cycles.