# toArray() returns object[]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, toarray

I am trying to convert an ArrayList to an Array using toArray(), but it returns an object[] instead of double[]. See below:

```
double [] arr = arrList.toArray(new Double[arrList.size()]);
```

I'm getting an Incompatible Types error.

This is what the arrList contains:

```
I/System.out: [0.0, 2.455430030822754, 1.834529995918274, 0.7368429899215698, -0.5264459848403931, -1.5101100206375122, -1.8526500463485718, -1.6131700277328491, -0.9388419985771179, 0.053711701184511185, 0.35541099309921265, -0.18560799956321716, -0.884518027305603, -1.4304900169372559, -1.5486400127410889, -0.943471014499, 0.0]
```

This is how it is obtained:

```
private void rec(SensorEvent event) {

    double x = event.values[0];

    arrList.add(x);

}
```

I've tried without sizing the array (i.e. using new Double[0]) although I didn't think it would be the problem but that did not work either.

I looked for similar Qs online and all I found was on String examples, and I'm thinking Double might be the problem? Not too sure.

Quite new at this so apologies if obvious.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That has now been resolved

Comment: @ItsLogic, explain. I haven't heard of array unboxings (and that'd be a bad feature for performance reasons).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes but toArray() cannot be applied to double[]

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  I was referring to that an edit was made to the post changing double[] to Double[]

Comment: @ItsLogic, I see. I thought you referred to the first comment.

Comment: @pizza That's fine. You call `toArray()` correctly. But you assign the `Double[]` that it returns to a `double[]`. Just fix the declaration as I describe in my answer.

Comment: It appears there's some confusion over what the actual problem is. Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] (← read the linked page) demonstrating the problem, along with the _exact_ error messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
double [] arr = arrList.toArray(new Double[arrList.size()]);
```

`double[]` is a different type than `Double[]`. While Java can convert between `double` and `Double` with autoboxing and autounboxing, it cannot convert from `Double[]` to `double[]`. You can fix the problem with:

```
Double [] arr = arrList.toArray(new Double[arrList.size()]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still getting an incompatible types error though, not too sure why unfortunately.

Comment: @pizza, then edit your question to show how you construct your `arrList` variable.

Comment: I've edited my question. Might be because I define the entries in the arrList as double?

Comment: @pizza Are you saying you're using a `List<double>`? Because that's illegal in Java—primitives cannot be used as generic type arguments. However, `List<Double>` is perfectly legal. And when using a `List<Double>` you can add primitive `double` elements to it with ease due to autoboxing.

Comment: thank you @Slaw. I now get Double[] but wanted to get double[] so I could use in DoubleFFT_1D.realforward(double[] a). Not sure if there is a way to do that?

Comment: @pizza Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109988/how-do-i-convert-double-to-double

Comment: @pizza Check the question Slaw posted and if you still need help, post a new question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
Double[] array = arrList.toArray(Double[]::new);
```

Note, that method references were introduced in java 8 and the method in java 11. Please refer to Code-Apprentice's answer for java 7 compilant solution.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting "Method references are not supported at language level '7'" though.

Comment: @pizza sorry, forgot to mention, method references were introduced in java 8, please refer to Code-Apprentice's answer for java 7 compilant solution

Comment: @pizza, the most important part of this answer is first `Double[]`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes my bad!

Comment: Note that [`Collection#toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) was added in _Java 11_.